# Posgresql always inserts some additional tables as if I created a database from a template

Tags: postgresql

Each time I'm creating a database via "psql" or via some tool which probably also does it via "psql", Postgresq always creates some additional tables. Previously  I had a database with those tables, yes, but it's long gone and at that time I even didn't create a template with those tables whatsoever.

However, it looks like there's a template database to which they belong or something like it which I don't see. However, in PgAdmin there's no such a database! There're no templates either. Again, each time I'm creating a new databases, those tables are added automatically.

How can I completely remove those bloody tables from postgresql, where should I look for them?

Answer (score 1):

Every PostgreSQL install has a Template0 and a Template1. Template0 is not supposed to be tampered with, it's for Pg. Template1 has the template that is used by default with `CREATE DATABASE`. It routinely has modifications by users, especially in multitenant systems.

- [Template Databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

Answer sourced from [Guillaume Lelarge](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Howto-see-template-objects-in-PGAdmin3-td5744939.html)

> You first need to check the "Show System Objects in the treeview" in the 
>   Options dialog. Then, they'll be available in the Databases node of the 
>   treeview.

Comment: how can I make tempalte0/1 appear in PgAdmin?

Comment: @Jodari pgadmin3 or pgadmin4?

Comment: 3...................